# Looping through a nested JSON object in datatables

Tags: javascript, python, django, datatables

I'm looking to iterate through a JSON object in javascript. Right now it is loading each "item" into a single cell instead of putting 1 item per column across a row. For example, I want to get:

```
Period         Name          Amount
1/1/2014    Accounting       $500.00
```

What I'm getting is:

```
       Period                             Name                Amount
1/1/2014, Accounting, $500       1/1/2014, Finance, $750    ...,...,...
```

The view producing the JSON object is:

```
def BudgetJson(request):
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    resultset = models.Expense.objects.filter(category_id=1)
    d = {'data' : [[[model.expensePeriod, model.expenseName, 
           model.expenseAmount] for model in resultset]]}
    return JsonResponse(d)
```

I'm using the `datatables` library to render the table, and using AJAX to receive the JSON object (via a URL):

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#expenses').DataTable( {
            "ajax": '{% url "property:budget:budget_json" %}'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I understand that my view is outputting a single key/item, which is why I'm getting that result - what I want to know is, is it better to let the JavaScript loop through the JSON object, and is that possible using the `datatables` UI library? Or should I change the structure of the JSON object that the view is outputting?

Comment: What version of *Datatables* are you using? I ask because there was a complete overhaul of the API in 1.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way,

producing `JSON` Object:

```
def BudgetJson(request):
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    out_list = []
    resultset = models.Expense.objects.filter(category_id=1)
    for model in resultset:
        temp_dict = {'expense_period': model.expensePeriod, 'expense_name':model.expenseName, 'expense_amount':model.expenseAmount }
        out_list.append(temp_dict)
    data = {'data' : out_list }
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

and inside your `<script>` tag the `datatable` will as

```
$('#expenses').DataTable( {
                    "ajax" : "your-url",
                    "columns" : [
                    {"data" : "expense_period"},
                    {"data" : "expense_name"},
                    {"data" : "expense_amount"},
                    ]
                });
```

This will work. :)